# How to calculate the required thickness of a material to withstand a certain force or acceleration?

Tags: materials, stresses

I am using a sheet of a certain material to dampen a product. Now, I have been looking at different soft dampening materials, and they're all defined by their durometer scale and other factors.

Which factor should I look at and how should I use it to determine how thick the sheet should be to withstand a certain amount of vertical force or acceleration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question spans a substantial amount of the field of mechanics of materials. *Some* of the essential aspects of making this question answerable include diagrams, a description of the exact material and loads, and an extremely specific definition of "withstand". At that point, somebody may be able to refer you to a model or guideline.

Comment: Take a college course called "deformable bodies" and/or "machine design."